# WebP integration and arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, image, arm64, webp

I am trying to update an app that is using Google's WebP.framework. The problem is that the project has to support arm64 architecture, but the WebP.framework does not.

I am using 0.4.0 version of the framework. Couldn't find the library compiled for arm64 anywhere in the net. I tried to build it myself, edited iosbuild.sh script that Google provided, but it fails with error  "autogen.sh: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download `libwebp-0.4.2.tar.gz` here: http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html

Expand that, cd into it, and execute `./iosbuild.sh`.

I haven't tested it out, but for me that successfully built the WebP.framework for these architectures:

```
iPhoneSimulator iPhoneOS-V7 iPhoneOS-V7s iPhoneOS-V7-arm64
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why Google's "latest version link" is to 0.4.0 and not to 0.4.2. Hope your answer will help other mislead people too.
I would have voted up for you, but I do not have enough reputation.